# Selenium - How to find a link object

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have the following HTML on a page I am testing in IE11 using Java.

```
<a href="BCreate.asp?Tab=Batches&amp;View=Batches"><span class="link_bar link_bar_link">Create New</span></a>
```

I get an error if I try to find by linkText:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create New")).click();
```

Error using xpath (the xpath validates to that link just fine in IE, Chrome, and FireFox):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/nobr/a[2]/span")).click();
```

I also tried to find by class, but no luck:

```
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.className("link_bar link_bar_link"));
WebElement childElement = parentElement.findElement(By.linkText("Create New"));
childElement.click();
```

Any ideas how to find and click on this link?

Comment: What about `By.partialLinkText("Create New")`?

Comment: Same error when using partialLinkText as well.

Comment: What is the Exception ?

Comment: Please update your question with the errors you get for each attempt.

Comment: What about driver.findElement(By.XPATH(//*[contains(text(),'Create New')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the link object with text as **Create New** you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='View=Batches']>span.link_bar.link_bar_link"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'View=Batches')]/span[@class='link_bar link_bar_link' and contains(.,'Create New')]"));
  ```